# Once I have a many-to-many relationship set up in my flask app, how do I create the associations without manually committing them in the shell?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm working on a Flask app for a game guild website. I have run into something that I've been unable to find any tutorials on. I have used Python, I have used MySQL, and I have used Flask but I have never tried to combine all of this together until now. Forgive my ignorance. I know how to manually create relationships in MySQL but I'm trying to do this with SQLAlchemy in my Flask app. So far, I have been able to figure out how to create one-to-many relationships and I can add/edit/delete database entries from my web forms (WTForms).

A system can have many planets and a planet can have many locations. A location can have many suppliers (stores) and a supplier can have many locations. I created an association table with the two table ids as columns and i created relationships in each table model. I can browse the database and see that all the tables are there. Now I need to figure out how to make the associations each time a new entry is made.

Specifically, I have a locations table, a suppliers table, and a locations_suppliers table. When I add a new supplier in my flask app, I want it to make the association to the location then as well. The weapons store "Live Fire Weapons" has 5 storefronts at 5 different locations, for example. I want to add Live Fire Weapons as a supplier for all 5 locations using WTForms and SQLAlchemy.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, redirect, url_for
#import sqlite3
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from datetime import datetime, date
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_user, LoginManager, login_required, logout_user,     current_user
from webforms import LoginForm, MemberForm, NameForm, UserForm, SystemForm, BodyForm,     LocationForm, SupplierForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'

# Database Setup and Models
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:********@localhost/solat'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

# association table for many-to-many relationship between suppliers and locations
locations_suppliers = db.Table('locations_suppliers',
                            db.Column('location_id', db.Integer,     db.ForeignKey('locations.location_id')),
                            db.Column('supplier_id', db.Integer,     db.ForeignKey('suppliers.supplier_id')),
                          )

class Locations(db.Model):
  location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  location_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False, unique=True)
  location_type = db.Column(db.String(80))
  location_habitable = db.Column(db.String(80))
  location_affiliation = db.Column(db.String(80))
  # Foreign key to link to a Body (refers to the primary key of the Body)
  body = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('bodies.body_id'))
  # A location can have many suppliers
  suppliers = db.relationship('Suppliers', secondary=locations_suppliers, backref='supplier')

class Bodies(db.Model):
  body_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  body_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False, unique=True)
  body_type = db.Column(db.String(80))
  body_habitable = db.Column(db.String(80))
  body_affiliation = db.Column(db.String(80))
  # Foreign key to link to a System (refers to the primary key of the system)
  system = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('systems.system_id'))
  # A body can have many locations
  locations = db.relationship('Locations', backref='location')

class Suppliers(db.Model):
  supplier_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  supplier_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
  supplier_type = db.Column(db.String(80))
  supplier_zone = db.Column(db.String(80))
  # A supplier can have many locations
  locations = db.relationship('Locations', secondary=locations_suppliers, backref='sup_location')

class Systems(db.Model):
  system_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  system_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False, unique=True)
  system_type = db.Column(db.String(80))
  system_size = db.Column(db.Integer)
  system_affiliation = db.Column(db.String(80))
  # A system can have many bodies
  bodies = db.relationship('Bodies', backref='body')

class SupplierForm(FlaskForm):
    supplier_name = StringField('Supplier Name:', validators=[DataRequired()])
    supplier_type = StringField('Supplier Type:')
    supplier_zone = StringField('Supplier Zone:')
    location = IntegerField('Location:')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/add_supplier', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def add_supplier():
  form = SupplierForm()
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    supplier = Suppliers(supplier_name=form.supplier_name.data,     supplier_type=form.supplier_type.data, supplier_zone=form.supplier_zone.data,     location=form.location.data)
    # clear the form
    form.supplier_name.data = ''
    form.supplier_type.data = ''
    form.supplier_zone.data = ''
    form.location.data = ''
    # add post to database
    db.session.add(supplier)
    db.session.commit()
    # return a message
    flash("Supplier Created Successfully")
  suppliers = Suppliers.query.order_by(Suppliers.supplier_id)
  # redirect to the webpage
  return render_template('add_supplier.html', form=form, suppliers=suppliers)
```

`add_supplier.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>
        Add Supplier
      </title>
    </head>
    <body>
      {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
          <strong>{{ message }}</strong>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">    </button>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}

      <h1>Add Supplier</h1>
      <br>
      <div class="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-dark text-warning fw-bold rounded">
        <form method="POST">
          {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

          {{ form.supplier_name.label(class="form-label") }}
          {{ form.supplier_name(class="form-control") }}
          <br>
          {{ form.supplier_type.label(class="form-label") }}
          {{ form.supplier_type(class="form-control") }}
          <br>
          {{ form.supplier_zone.label(class="form-label") }}
          {{ form.supplier_zone(class="form-control") }}
          <br>
          {{ form.location.label(class="form-label") }}
          {{ form.location(class="form-control") }}
          <br>
          {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-warning text-dark fw-bold") }}
        </form>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <h1>Supplier List</h1>
      <br>
      <table class="table table-dark table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
      {% for supplier in suppliers %}
        <tr>
          <td class="text-warning">Location: {{ supplier.supplier.location_name }} - Supplier Name: {{ supplier.supplier_name }} - Supplier Type: {{ supplier.supplier_type }} - Zone: {{ supplier.supplier_zone }} -  <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
      </table>
      <br><br>
    </body>
  </html>
{% endblock %}
```